# matplotlib: plot durations with nice and dynamic formatting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to make a dates (on x) vs. durations of time (on y) plots and need to have smart formatting for the y axis.  My data is of the format: '0:00:02.994000'  (0 hrs, 0 min, 2 seconds and 994000 microseconds).

The data could range from as little as a few seconds to more than 12 hours, I'd guess, though generally *for any given plot* most data points would be in the same units (sec, min, or hr).

The problem is, sometimes there will be outliers that are in a different unit.  E.g., there may be a plot in which most durations are within 1-3 hrs, but now and then there is a datapoint of 5 minutes, or even 30 seconds.  Or it could be another one with mostly datapoints in minutes, but an occasional long or short one in hours or seconds.

I want to pick a good (dynamic) way to format the y axis.  There are two issues:

1) Should I analyze the data to see what units the *majority* of datapoints are in and then use that as the y axis units?  That is, if most are durations of minutes, then the y axis should be given in minutes.  If most are in hours, the y axis should be hours, etc...  This way the formatting is most appropriate for the type of data displayed.

2) If a plot's y units are given in terms of minutes (because of point #1), but a user wants to zoom in (with the zoom tool) on a datapoint that is only a few seconds, I'd like the formatter to change the y scaling to be in terms of seconds.  I don't want to have express durations on the y axis as anything like "0.0335" minutes, but rather "2 seconds".

Any suggestions for how to approach this would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Che

Comment: How about a logarithmic y axis?

Comment: There is also a possibility for calculating the range and reformatting the y axis with a zoom. I will just search for you and post it here, but I think the logarithmic plot should help you also!

Answer (score 0):

You could register an event handler that mucks with the y data based on ylim.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
scale = get_scale(ylim)
def tweak_y(event):
    new_ylim = ax.get_ylim() 
    if new_ylim == ylim:
        return
    ylim = new_ylim
    if get_scale(ylim) != scale:
        # tweak ydata and replot
        pass

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', tweak_y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to use the datetime.timedelta string formatting, you can create the formatter like this:

```
def timeTicks(x, pos):
    d = datetime.timedelta(seconds=x)
    return str(d)
formatter = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(timeTicks)
```

Which can be applied to an axis using `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)`, this will scale when the user zooms. Note that this does not address the majority issue, but might be useful for others in similar situations.